# How does the Sun warm a person? Is it convection, Conduction or Radiation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, sun

I know that heat transfer can be conduction, radiation or convection, but I don't know which one it is.

Comment: If you understand what conduction, convection, and radiation are, then you can figure out which of them applies to heat from the Sun.

Answer (score 1):

Is the person touching the sun? conduction needs contact of solids.

Convection is when a fluid is moving in bulk  brings changes in the ambient temperature,  as the wind does. The temperature of the atmosphere depends on convection and indirectly the persons living in this atmosphere.

The sun is a ball of plasma millions of kilometers away and [its radiation,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight) traveling through vacuum, enters the atmosphere and part of it  reaches the person directly, to warm him/her.

The direct radiation also heats up solid matter , the ground can get very hot, and it is part of the heat of the atmosphere . Radiation heats a person directly, and indirectly both conduction and convection play a role in the heat felt by the person.

Comment: It's true that only radiation can warm the person directly, but the other two types can be involved in indirect heating (specifically -- radiation will be the first step, it can but does not have to be the last)